# File IO performance on SD card

Tags: android, linux, performance, file-io

all

When I try to read some media file from sd card after the first time I insert to the device, the read performance is much worse than the second time, does anybody have any idea about this  phenomena, and how can I avoid this problem, I tried open and fopen, but the results are the same, I just want read performance is the same, no matter when I insert SD card, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `O_DIRECT` (see [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)) when opening the file will bypass the buffer cache.  This is often not a good idea, but I would expect it to be more consistent from run to run.

Keep in mind that using `O_DIRECT` requires that the memory read into be `SC_PAGESIZE` aligned and read in blocks which are multiples of `SC_PAGESIZE`.

Comment: :(, I have tried this flag, it can work, but the performance is even worse on android device..., anyway, thanks

Comment: But I'd bet real money that it's consistent from run to run!

Comment: Hi, Brian, I could not get your point, do you mean O_DIRECT indeed can improve performance? But I tried on device, it cannot. and what's the problem?

Comment: No, `O_DIRECT` will not necessarily help performance.  But you asked " I just want read performance is the same, no matter when I insert SD card."  `O_DIRECT` will likely solve that problem.  Your problem has "no" solution because you want to be able to read data from a medium that has hardware throughput limitations.  Try changing the hardware (both the medium and the card reader) and I would expect the performance to improve (though it will likely never come close to the memory cache performance).  Digital Photography has a similar problem, look to those vendors for equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying it's worse for the first read than subsequent reads before you remove the device?  If so, this is normal - it's due to buffering.  Basically the system is using the system RAM to speed up the perceived speed of the device.

If you remove the card after unmounting it and then put it back and remount it I would expect the first read would again be slower, then subsequent reads would appear to be faster again.

Comment: Hi, Jared, Thanks for your reply, it exactly like what you said, I am just wondering how to improve the first time performance, is there any possible to stop buffering for the first time, and will it be helpful？

Comment: Usually, buffering is useful, and you should leave the system doing it. Reading from an SD card is always slower than reading from RAM!

Comment: hi Basile, you are right, buffering most time is useful, but I am wondering if without buffering, whether the first time performance will be better, I have tried O_DIRECT flag, the performance is even worse for the first time, I got confused.

Comment: The bottleneck is hardware limitation of SD card interface. No software tricks could overcome them...

Comment: Don't think of buffering as slowing down the first read - because it probably isn't (maybe a percent or two).  Think of buffering as speeding up subsequent reads.  You can try the O_DIRECT trick mentioned, but I think it will only hurt.

Comment: Jared，you are right, I have tried, with O_DIRECT it will be even worse